# For what is the socket located just beside the DVD drive in Dell E6430 used?

Tags: dell-latitude, sockets

I just bought a new laptop from my computer teacher (where I do Web designing Course) few days ago. I was given only three things: A Bag, An Adapter, and The Laptop.

I was not given any guide (I don't know really whether it is to be given or not). Thus, I don't know still about many parts of the laptop. But yesterday at night, when I was exploring the sockets (or whatever it is called), I found a socket which was located just beside the laptop's DVD Drive as:

[image: here]

[image: here (zoomed)]

Can anyone tell me what that socket is used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the tab you use to pull the DVD drive out of the laptop.  Push it in and it will click closed.  Push it again, it will pop out.  You can then pull the DVD drive out.